# Bootstrap 4 - nested navigation link opens tab content only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a vertical nested navigation which opens a tab when it is clicked. However, the link in the nested level causes the tab opens to start misbehaving.

I've a JS fiddle here that illustrates the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/2v2qwnkc/1/

To reproduce:

1. Click on `Reports > Phone`. This would load "Phone Content" into the tab content area as expected.
2. Now, click on `Home`. Nothing would happen.
3. Next, click on `Profile`. Profile content would load.
4. Finally, click on `Phone` again. Nothing would happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the core of your problem is nesting `.nav` elements.

[`tab.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/tab.js) plugin is acting like your parent and child `nav`s are separate. You can tell by the simple fact that it's letting two elements have an `.active` class at the same time:

[image]

The actual problem seems to be on line `148` of the plugin:

```
activeElements = $(container).children(Selector.ACTIVE)
```

`children` method returns only direct children of your parent `.nav`. `#phone-tab` is a descendant, not a child, so it's never included.

If we get rid of your nested `.nav`, clicking on Home link will work, but Phone will remain marked as active. If we dig deeper, we find that the line responsible for removing `.active` class only works on the first element:

```
const active = activeElements[0]
```

My conclusion is that you'd need to heavily modify this plugin to make it work for your case, or create your own custom solution.